# Weasel Program, Not understanding Python random library?

Tags: python, random, for-loop

I'm attempting a Python version of Richard Dawkin's [Weasel Program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weasel_program) that demonstrates the difference between random selection versus cumulative selection and am having some problems with my mutation algorithm. I'm thinking perhaps I don't understand how to use the Python random library. Here's the offending bit of code:

```
#Cumulative selection guesser
while counter <  2:
    for i in range(gen):
        for j in range(len(child)):
            mutation = random.randint(0,99)
            if mutation in range(5):
                 child[j] = random.choice(chars)
        offspring.append(child)
    counter += 1
```

"Counter" is used for testing and will be changed to a test for equality with the target phrase once the code is complete, "child" is a list of 28 random letters, "gen" is the number of generations and is just a constant number like 100 or 50, "chars" is a string of the uppercase alphabet and the space character, and "offspring" is an empty list I want to put all my generated "children" in. If this doesn't make sense I can include the rest of the code, but the main problem I have is that every child in each generation is exactly the same.

What should be happening is the code goes through each element in "child" rolls the dice for a mutation, if the mutation happens change that specific element in child to a new random character. Then the "child" gets added to the list of offspring.  So the offspring should be something like:

DDSMMHYODHFZTZRKWQUQYGMLUDB

DDSMMHYODHFZTZRKW**M**UQYGMLUDB

DDSM**I**HYODHFZTZRKWQUQYGMLUDB

D**P**SMMHYODHFZTZRKWQUQYGML**Q**DB

(variations bolded)

times how many are specified by the variable "gen". Instead I get each child exactly the same with no variations, like this:

DDSMMHYODHFZTZRKWQUQYGMLUDB

DDSMMHYODHFZTZRKWQUQYGMLUDB

DDSMMHYODHFZTZRKWQUQYGMLUDB

DDSMMHYODHFZTZRKWQUQYGMLUDB

etc. I've spent a long time trying to figure out what the problem is and have tried testing each part of the code separately and it appears to function as I would expect. The only thing I can think is that the value for "mutation" is not changing because when "random.randint()" is called it only generates a random integer once. Is this how the random function works? I would expect that a new random integer would be generated for every iteration of the for loop.

If anyone has any thoughts or suggestions I would appreciate it. I'm banging my head against the wall here. Also, I can post the entire code if it helps. Thanks!

Comment: Python 2 or 3? You cannot change a string, btw.

Comment: What does print(mutation) show?

Comment: Apart from the fact that strings are immutable, your code *should* run fine. Check your assumptions about `gen` and `counter` with `pdb` or `print` statements / function calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a copy of `child` before you append it to `offspring`:

```
offspring.append(child[:])
```

`child[:]` returns a new list with the same contents as `child`. Since it is a new list, future mutations of `child` will not affect `child[:]`.

If you don't do this, `offspring` will contain multiple references to the *exact same list*. So every mutation of `child` affects every item in `offspring`. Every item in `offspring` ends up equal to the last value of `child`.

Comment: This solved the problem, thanks so much! I guess I should go read up more on Python's list type as I obviously didn't understand it well enough. I appreciate the help, though, because I was at a point where I didn't know what I was not comprehending. Thanks again.